# Hide a div following css animation on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

As the current time, I have CSS3 Animations being triggered on button click, and all works well. Its an animation to represent the plant life cycle, working in 5 stages, each stage shows an image and corresponding text.

However, if i click stage 1, then stage 2, and want to click stage 1 again to view the supporting text again, whilst hiding the image from stage two, I cannot seem to be able to do it.

JSFiddle for your convinience:

http://jsfiddle.net/YUC3d/

Live View of current stage:

http://www.mattmeadows.info/MFTW2/howplantsgrow.html

Javascript:

```
$(function() {  
    $("#stage1").click(function() {  
        $("#Seed1,#infoBox1").toggleClass("animate")   
    });  
    $("#stage2").click(function() {  
        $("#Seed2,#infoBox2").toggleClass("animate")   
    });  
    $("#stage3").click(function() {  
        $("#Seed3,#infoBox3").toggleClass("animate")   
    });  
    $("#stage4").click(function() {  
        $("#Seed4,#infoBox4").toggleClass("animate")   
    });
    $("#stage5").click(function() {  
        $("#Seed5,#infoBox5").toggleClass("animate")   
    });
});
```

HTML Segment being animated:

```
<div id="Seed1" class="target">
</div> <!-- end of Seed1 -->
<div id="infoBox1">
Text for stage 1 Text for stage 1 Text for stage 1 Text for stage 1 Text for stage 1 
</div>
```

(There are 5 of these div combinations in total

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes show
{
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

#Seed1
{
opacity:0;
}

#Seed1.animate
{
-webkit-animation-name: show;
-webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;   
-webkit-animation-direction: normal;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#infoBox1
{
width: 400px;
height: 100px;
background:white;
position: absolute;
bottom: 425px;
margin-left: 25px;
border-radius: 10px;
opacity:0;
}

#infoBox1.animate
{
-webkit-animation-name: show;
-webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;   
-webkit-animation-direction: normal;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that 'animate' is the 'on' class (it seems to be), try making a method that resets everything then animate the specific element:

```
function setStage(stage) {

     var numberOfStages = 5;

     for (i=1; i <= numberOfStages; i++) {
         if (i == stage) {
             $("#infoBox" + i).addClass("animate");
             $("#Seed" + i).addClass("animate");
         } else if (i < stage) {
             $("#infoBox" + i).removeClass("animate");
             $("#Seed" + i).addClass("animate");
         } else {
             $("#infoBox" + i).removeClass("animate");
             $("#Seed" + i).removeClass("animate");
         }
     }

}
```

Example use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#stage1").click(function() {  
        setStage(1);  
    }); 

    //stage 2,3,5 etc...

    $("#stage4").click(function() {  
        setStage(4);  
    }); 

});
```

Comment: Have altered the resetState as suggested, however it still only shows 1 image at a time, instead of a progressive style.
(Live link in original question is an example of whats happening)

Comment: Ok, so I think I get what you want now - text bx should be whichever was clicked last and images should show all stages (seeds) up to the last stage we clicked. Is that irght?

Comment: Say stage 1 is clicked : Shows text for stage 1 and image.
Stage 2 clicked: Shows text for stage 2 and image for stage 1 AND 2

and so on for all stages.

However, i'd still like to be able to click any button to view in any order, whilst the previous seed images are kept

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've meant. I've edited the answer, it should do what you want

Comment: Does this edited answer replace all the JS i previously have?

Comment: Yes, try it out, if it's what you want please make sure to pick the answer for me :)

Comment: Hi there, i've tried what you've suggested (live link shows updated version) however it doesn't show anything now :(

Comment: sorry change if (i = stage) { to if (i == stage) {

Comment: I tested it - the script works, but you need to wait until the page is ready to bind your click functions, because the buttons don't exist otherwise. I've updated my answer to show you how (the second part)

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that 'animate' is the 'on' class (it seems to be), try making a method that resets everything then animate the specific element:

```
function resetState() {
     //you can use classes here to make it neater
     $("#Seed1,#infoBox1,#Seed2,#infoBox2,#Seed3,#infoBox3,#Seed4,#infoBox4,#Seed5,#infoBox5").removeClass("animate");  
}
```

Example use:

```
$("#stage1").click(function() {  
    resetState();
    $("#Seed1,#infoBox1").toggleClass("animate");   
});
```

Comment: Whilst this nearly does as I would like, is there any way to modify the example given so that the image stays (#Seed1) whilst #infoBox1,2,3,4,5 change?

Comment: You could send in the id of the image you don't want to reset, I'll add it in a separate answer